# How to "snmpwalk" a tomcat with activated JMX to monitor it

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, monitoring, jmx

I have an application that runs within a tomcat (a handful of java servlets) on linux. Now I am tasked to monitor the ressources (such as CPU, memory usage, etc.) within this tomcat (not the single servlets).

I am not a programmer (so I cannot change code) and I am not allowed to change anything within the code. I am also not very familiar with Java (so my apologies if I throw a few things together).

The only thing I can do is start tomcat with java-parameters that activate jmx. So I can remotly check tomcat and the application/servlets running within from remote using JMX.

Question:
What tools (or possibilities) are available to find out what kind of monitoring/ressource information the tomcat (or application with the mbeans) is offering?

I am thinking along the lines of a snmpwalk which would allow me to discover the information provided by snmp. However, I have no idea how to do this with java and jmx (found tons of articles on the internet on how to program it, but that is out of the question).

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: jvisualvm and its mbean plugin could help

Answer (score 0):

You are better off looking at an APM tool to fit this use case. I work for AppDynamics and we do just this. The other common tools are Dynatrace and New Relic. These tools will attach to a Java application at runtime and provide deep monitoring, visibility, transaction tracing, and troubleshooting capabilities. AppDynamics also automatically baselines all of the metrics and alerts you when things start having issues.

Comment: Agree with Jonah but you may really want to start with jvisualvm - just as RC suggest - to explore whats out there. maybe sit down with your devs to help you in picking the right metrics. APM tools will just provide you out-of-the-box visiblity without going through a lot of config. I work for Dynatrace but would also point out that if you google for Tomcat Performnace Monitoring you find a huge list of tools

Comment: SO monitoring JMX is a good way to "monitor your app". Interesting perspective, I'll disagree.